# Perform unit tests on published web-api

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to perform automated unit tests on my web-api project after publish it on IIS but I don't know how ? I can launch tests in Visual Studio, no problem for that.

I have some unit tests in a different project, must I generate the unit tests project an deploy it in the api-web site, and use another soft to perform tests ?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Unit-Tests are offline. This sounds like a integration or aceptance test..

Comment: Unit tests should be run after you build the application and before it is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you are proposing here does not sound like Unit tests. They are integration tests that test the entire integration and end to end working across application layers. 
Regarding the automated execution, you can easily set that up using CI/CD. You can use VSTS or TeamCity like solutions to run your test cases at a particular schedule. Or, you can run your tests using command line from a system, that has Visual Studio installed.